# SQL Server : Multiple relationship for the same field

Tags: sql-server

I have this situation :

Table : Article

Id

name

category

.........................

Table : Services

id

name

nr

value

---

Table : Sell_item

Id

item_id

quantity

price

value

---

Now the problem is this : The field Item_id on the sell_item table can be the id for  an Article or a Service. So I need to create a double relationship for this field one with Article table an one with Service table.

Is this possible ?

If not , or if I'm wrong how can I solve this situation ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of discussed in [this thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) , but the basic gist is that a foreign key can only be used to express a link and dependency between only two tables.

From pure SQL you might be able to write a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) that could do some of these checks.  This would require that you still need to make checks on the data during inserts updates and deletes to ensure consistency.

If you the data is being consumed by another application that supports the concept (such as hibernate) you could a ***discriminator*** or [table per class hierarchy](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritence-table-per-hierarchy-mapping/)  which provides certain frameworks with the ability to programmaticaly make the determination on the type of data and where to load it from, but this will not provide you with the constraints at the DB level that you are looking for.

Hope this helps a bit.